# Quick way to grant Exec permissions to DB role for many stored procs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssms

Consider the scenario where a database has a SQL Database Role or Application Role. The task is to grant Execute permissions to ***n*** stored procedures.

When using SQL Management Studio, there's a nice screen to help apply permissions to objects for a Role.

[image: SQL Management Studio]

Here are the steps to apply permissions:

- select the object that you want to grant/deny permissions in the list of *Securables*.
- navigate to the list of *Explicit Permissions* below.
- select the Grant or Deny checkbox as appropriate.

Repeat the above for ***n*** objects. Fire up some music to keep yourself entertained while doing this for 100+ objects! There's got to be a better way! It's a clickfest of major proportions.

**Question**:

Is there a faster way to perform this task using SQL Server Management Studio 2005? Perhaps another GUI tool (preferably free)?

Any suggestions for creating T-SQL scripts to automatically perform this task? i.e. create a table of all stored procedure names, loop, and apply the exec permissions?

Comment: Have you considered having all procedures in one schema and then grant execute on the said schema?

Comment: This is why GUI tools and reliance on them, suck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CREATE PROC SProcs_GrantExecute( 
    @To AS NVARCHAR(255)
    , @NameLike AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SchemaLike as NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'dbo'
    ) AS
/*
 Proc to Authorize a role for a whole bunch of SProcs at once
*/
DECLARE @sql as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + '
 GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::['+ROUTINE_SCHEMA+'].['+ROUTINE_NAME+'] TO '+@To+';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_NAME LIKE @NameLike
 AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA LIKE @SchemaLike

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

This is Injectable as heck, so keep it for Admin use only.

---

I just want to add that Remus's suggestion of using schemas is the preferred approach, where that is workable.

Comment: Tremendous! You just saved this junior programmer a lot of time. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like overkill!

Answer (score 36):

```
USE database_name;
GRANT EXECUTE TO [security_account];
```

Don't forget the brackets :)

Comment: How can I verify this either in the SSMS Gui or via TSQL?

Answer (score 18):

you can do this, however I'm not entirely sure how secure this is.

```
/* CREATE A NEW ROLE */
CREATE ROLE db_executor

/* GRANT EXECUTE TO THE ROLE */
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON myproc TO x
```

where x =

1. SQL User
2. Role
3. AD Group/Account

Answer (score 2):

Simply update the dbo schema and set add an EXECUTE permission on this schema to the desired user/role.